# How to call parameterized constructor from angular js controller through $http url?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to call Initailly the parameterized constructor from the angular js $http url that which maps the action method in MVC .
My angular js controller code is as follows:-

```
var app = angular.module("ourSiteLogIn", []);
app.controller("ourSiteLogInController", function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.GetLogInByUserIdPassword = function () {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "User/GetLogInByUserIdPassword",
        params: {
            UserId: $scope.UserId,
            Password: $scope.Password
        }
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.User = response.data;
    }, function myError(reason) {
        $scope.error = reason.data;
    });
};

});
```

below is my controller :

```
  public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogIn _login;
    private readonly IExceptionLog _exceptionlog;

    public UserController()
    {

    }

    public UserController(ILogIn login, IExceptionLog exceptionLog)
    {
        _login = login;
        _exceptionlog = exceptionLog;
    }

  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetLogInByUserIdPassword(string UserId, string Password)
    {            
        try
        {
            Encrypt objEncrypt = new Encrypt();
            tblLogIn objtblLogIn = new tblLogIn();
            objtblLogIn = _login.GetLogInByUserIdPassword(UserId, objEncrypt.EncryptText(Password));
            return Json(objtblLogIn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _exceptionlog.insertExceptionLog(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

here the problem is i am getting _login as null value while calling this method "GetLogInByUserIdPassword" and this method is presnt in another project. And by default it is calling default constructor but not calling the parameterized constructor. Any ideas will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Why is there a default constructor here?  Dependencies are invalid and there's no way to set them in this case.  What happens if you remove it?

Comment: @stephen.vakil  i removed the default constructor  and when i call that action method from angular then it is showing Internal Server Error and it is not even calling to parameterized constructor and also action method. if that is the case i think here we need to do in some different way and dependencies also can't resolve.Thanks.

Comment: Have you set up an inversion of control container / DI in your MVC side?

Comment: @stephen.vakil  i used Unity DI Container in my MVC Side.

Comment: @stephen.vakil Thanks for the help. I did a mistake and now it is working fine.